# hpple XpathQuery ideas?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, xpath, hpple

I am using hpple to parse some HTML.  I am using Xcode 4.6 and iOS 6.1.  It looks like this.

[image: my HTML]

I can extract the text and images by using the following `XPathQueryStrings`.

Text ==> `//div[@class = 'entry-content']/p`

Images ==> `//div[@class = 'entry-content']//img/@src`

However, I also need to get the text near the bottom "Retiring Stamp Set PDF".  This text changes, but the format is usually the same.  I tried the following path,

`div[@class = 'entry-content']//a[@title]//text()`

But that did not work.  I am placing all these in an array and I can see that I get a null back for that entry, but I want to get the text.  I looked at the XPath Syntax, but can't make it any further.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out!  So for anyone that has viewed this here is the answer according to my HTML file.

To get the text you use....

//div[@class = 'entry-content']//a[@title]//*

This returns all the text under the a div with a title.